# Windows GPO for Intranet Site only adds all subdomains

Tags: windows, group-policy, internet-explorer, intranet

I'm using [this GPO](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/askie/2012/06/05/how-to-configure-internet-explorer-security-zone-sites-using-group-polices/) in a windows domain to distribute the "Internet Zones" Internet Explorer settings.
Domain users apply that GPO, but the entry is wrong:

`example.com` is mapped as Zone Type 1 (Intranet)

Clients apply this rule as `*.example.com`

I've also added a mapping for `*.example.com` to troubleshoot, but the second level domain entry `example.com` just won't be applied on clients' machines. Locally, adding `example.com` in IE settings works just fine.

[image: My GPO settings (German)]

Is there any syntax or rule-checks I'm issing? Programs run from the network share `\\example.com\` still show a security warning because the second-level domain `example.com` isn't included with that `*.example.com` entry

Comment: 1) Can you provide more detail on how your GPO is configured? A screenshot would be great. 2) Exactly what entry do you want to appear on the client? `file://example.com'? Something else?

Comment: Added a picture and Link to the GPO I'm using. Expected result for this GPO is an entry "example.com" in the IE Intranet Site list. However, this GPO is applied as "*.example.com", so that doesn't include "example.com"... Finally, this entry is to suppress a warning dialogue when executing something from the network share \\example.com, which should work fine having "Include all UNC Paths" selected (default).

Comment: `Programs run from the network share \\example.com\ still show a security warning`. What security warning?

Comment: @NoMad:  You also need to provide how you are confirming the setting is not going into effect on the computers. Typically this is done using gpresult /h gpresult.html to display the settings.

Comment: @GregAskew gpresult /h confirms what I see in the AD Group Policy window, there the entry is still shown as `example.com`, but in the actual Settings, there only is `*.example.com` after applying the GPO. The warning is the Windows dialog to confirm you want to run a file coming from an unknown location.

Comment: That's the expected behavior. If you enter domain.com, Internet Explorer displays it as *.domain.com. The group policy is just a delivery vehicle for the setting, and is working as expected. This isn't an issue with group policies or Internet Explorer settings.

Comment: How can this be expected behavior? As you can read above, setting it locally in the IE settings does not expand/interpret the entry `domain.com` as `*.domain.com` which excludes `domain.com` itself. Something in the process of applying the GPO modifies the value that I entered. And I can't find any documentation on why and when the string is parsed and modified, so I can't verify that this is expected behavior.